# Digital Logic 3 Light Switch In A Room Question

Tags: logic

There are three doors in a room with a light switch next to each one. You can turn on the light from any door when you enter, and you can turn-off the light from any door when you leave.

a) Write the truth table for the function
b) Use the Karnaugh map to see if it can be simplified
c) Draw logic circuit for the function
**d) Check if it is possible to realize function with a single logic gate**

Especially **d** is the hardest one for me to solve. Can you help me?
[If you wanna see the picture of question, click here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iQOx.jpg)

Comment: Could you tell us what you have tried so far? Did you get through parts a,b,c?

Comment: Also, what exactly is the "function" that is supposed to represent this function? Presumably, the output of any function in this context should be "true" or "false"; perhaps this should refer to whether the light is on or off. However, what are the *inputs* to this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Labelling the switches by each door as $A$, $B$, and $C$, and using digital electronics notation,

- Logical OR is represented with a $+$,
- AND is represented with multiplication. $A$ AND $B$ is $AB$,
- Negation is represented with an overline. Not $A$ is $\overline{A}$,
- "Exclusive or" (XOR) is represented as $\oplus$,

a Karnaugh map would look something like:

\begin{array}{c|cccc}
&\overline{A}\overline{B}&\overline{A}B&AB&A\overline{B}\\ \hline
\overline{C}&0&1&0&1\\
C&1&0&1&0
\end{array}

Unfortunately this doesn't simplify on the Karnaugh map in an obvious way. It can be simplified using the laws of Boolean algebra though.

\begin{align}
\overline{A}B\overline{C}+ABC+\overline{A}\overline{B}C+A\overline{B}\overline{C}\\
A(BC+\overline{B}\overline{C})+\overline{A}(B\overline{C}+\overline{B}C)\\
A(\overline{B\oplus C})+\overline{A}(B\oplus C)\\
A\oplus(B\oplus C)\\
\end{align}

Although it may look like you can't implement a single logic gate to realise function, since it is an application question, you could just recommend the 3-input XOR gate bellow:

[image]

XOR logic gates with more than 2 inputs are sometimes called "odd functions” or “modulo-2 sum functions", since they return TRUE whenever an odd number of their inputs are true, precisely the requirements for a light to turn on in your question.